# how to select special sphinx index

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I want to search in mytable2 with this php code.

```
$results = $s->query("foo","index2");
```

But it returns results from mytable. mytable and mytable2 are described in sphinx.conf.

this my configuration file: sphinx.conf

```
source src
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = 
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query       =       SELECT id,title,content FROM mytable

}
index index
{
    source          = src
    path            = /var/lib/sphinx/src1
}

source src2
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = 
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query       =       SELECT id,title,content FROM mytable2

}


index index2
{
    source          = src2
    path            = /var/lib/sphinx/src2
}
```

have I missed something or I just misunderstood what I was supposed to do?

Comment: The code you posted is correct. the query is searching index2, which is  linked to src2 which searches mytable2. Would suggest the issue is elsewhere. How confident are you of the diagnosis?

Comment: I changed index to index1 and src to src1 and it worked. Not so logical, unless there is a bug with sphinx